Can I apply the CKEditor magic line for <div> elements as well?
I am using CKEditor 5, version 40.2.0 within the context of Drupal 10 (not sure if the latter is relevant though).
The editor has a great feature that used to be called Magic Line in CKEditor 4, and I think in CKEditor5 it is called widgettypearound. This practically adds a nice border around an element and controls to add a new paragraph before or after the element "where normally it is impossible to place the caret due to limitations of web browsers."
Example:

While in CKEditor4 this used to apply to <div> elements as well, in CKEditor5 it does not, which makes advanced content editing without switching to Source nearly impossible. Is there a workaround or configuration I can change in order to allow the widgettypearound for <div>s too?
